# I think I fried my Raspberry Pi, but I'm not sure

Tags: python, power, relay

I was making connections from my Raspberry Pi to a relay module. While I was running some sample code, I noticed that after I had terminated the program I was still getting a high CPU usage (around 60%), but it didn't show anything in the task manager. I decided to reboot it hoping that everything will reset back to normal. It started booting normally, the logo came up and everything, and then suddenly the touchscreen turned off and started flashing black. And now it won't even boot up. Here is an image of the connections:

Over view of circuit connections:

[image: Over view of circuit connections]

Here are the GPIO connections that I made from the Raspberry Pi to the relay module.

Raspberry Pi:

[image: Raspberry Pi]

16-channel relay module:

[image: 16-channel relay module]

I also made the 5V connections from the Raspberry Pi to the relay module as well as the ground. Since I needed two 5V connections, the other one was being used for the display, so I decided to experiment and try to connect the 3.3V pin to the relay in addition to the single 5V pin.

3.3 V, 5 V and two ground pin connections from Pi:

[image: 3.3 V, 5 V and two ground pin connections from Pi]

Power connections to relay:

[image: Power connections to relay]

As you can see in the "Power connections to Relay" image, there are two wires on the right side. Those supply 12V at 1A directly to the relay module. This is the basic set up I had, and whenever I ran some code over it nothing would work.

This is the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.serwarnings(False)

x = [27,28,29,32,31,36,33,38,35,40]

for y in x:
    GPIO.setup(y,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(y, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(y,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Where did I go wrong, or why isn't my Raspberry Pi turning on anymore? As well as, what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: You seem to suggest you connected 3.3v and 5v to the relay board. That may have killed your Pi. If you needed another 5v you could have split one 5v into 2 as long as it didn’t draw too much power.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wire a Raspberry Pi to a 16 channel relay module? It won't work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99988/how-to-wire-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-16-channel-relay-module-it-wont-work)

Answer (score 1):

"I think I fried my Raspberry Pi but I'm not sure?" - **ALMOST certainly** - see my answer to your other question https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100014/8697