# Powering solenoid from batterypack

Tags: power, relay, breadboard

Im trying to power my 6V solenoid that is connected to my 8 channel 5V relay using my 8 x AA batterypack. The pi is being powered through an adapter and the relay from the VCC to 5V pi. When the LED to the channel which the solenoid is connected to lights up, the solenoid should trigger as well, but that's not the case.
There is nothing wrong with the solenoid, when its powered straight from the batterypack it works fine.

Relay: [https://www.amazon.com/JBtek-Channel-Module-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B00KTELP3I/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=relay+8+channel&qid=1569870908&s=gateway&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KTELP3I)

Solenoid: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B018HX0R2W/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B018HX0R2W)

[image]

Comment: This is **YET ANOTHER ** question about the appallingly designed relay module which is unsuitable for the Pi

Comment: I don't have any experience using this relay with the Pi, so I can't comment on if it's appalling, but are you sure it's wired up correctly? In your diagram the GPIO wire is attached to what's labeled IN1 but the solenoid is attached to relay K8. When you turn on the GPIO pin do you hear the relay click? Some Amazon reviews suggest it'd be better to connect VCC to +3.3V rather than +5V on the Pi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wire a Raspberry Pi to a 16 channel relay module? It won't work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99988/how-to-wire-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-16-channel-relay-module-it-wont-work)