# How to make a system that uses a mobile sim and that acts on a relay by ringing the sim

Tags: internet, relay, database

I want to create a system that has an internet connection via a mobile sim and allows owners of enabled telephone numbers to switch a relay by ringing the device sim.

The system must be able to register its IP address on dyndns in order to be accessible via url.

The system will be used to allow the opening of a gate only to owners of authorized telephone numbers, who through a call to the system will activate the relay which will pilot the arm for opening.

More precisely, the device must allow me remotely, via internet connection:

1) upload a list of telephone numbers to an archive;

2) enable / disable telephone numbers indicating whether they are always enabled or a date and time of enabling and disabling

3) have a log, downloadable remotely, of the various accesses with date and time

4) The relay must remain closed for a predefined time and then open automatically

What hardware is needed?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a system that has an **internet connection** via a mobile
>   sim and allows owners of enabled telephone numbers to switch a relay
>   by **ringing the device sim**.

In this instance, you need a SIM card module. The system just tries to upload some log files which is not too large hence you can buy a GSM module and make a 2G connection to your RPi.
Maybe in your area, using the 2G cellular network has expired and you thought that you must make a connection to DynDNS server so the 100kbps is not enough.

sixfab [Raspberry Pi 3G-4G/LTE Base Shield V2](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-3g-4glte-base-shield-v2/) can be a good option.

To see better module by the speed you want, check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=186248#p1176335) out.

---

> ... who through a call to the system will activate the **relay** which
>   will pilot the arm for opening.

It could help if you add more information about the relay. There is a lot of option.

**1-Channel:** [Vithconl PYXQ-9683 Photocoupler Relay Module 1-Channel 5V Compatible with Raspberry Pi, ARM, AVR, DSP, PIC - Open Source DIY Electronic Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XF6W3KH)

**2-Channel:** [beioust 2-Channel DC 5V Relay Switch Module Relay Module for Raspberry Pi ARM AVR DSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y5DRV5V)

**4-Channel:** [UNIVERSAL-SOLDER SIMPLY. SMARTER. ELECTRONICS. 4 Relay Module 10A / 250V, Opto-Isolated Inputs 3-24V - 5V Power Supply - for Arduino Raspberry Pi STM32](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06Y156FH2)

**8-Channel:** [Vithconl PYXQ-9684 Photocoupler Relay Module 8-Channel 5V Compatible with Raspberry Pi, ARM, AVR, DSP, PIC - Open Source DIY Electronic Kit](https://www.amazon.ca/Vithconl-PYXQ-9684-Photocoupler-8-Channel-Compatible/dp/B07XC29G2Y/ref=sr_1_11?qid=1578338737&refinements=p_lbr_characters_browse-bin%3AWonder%20Woman&s=toys&sr=1-11)

Check this [link out - Control a Relay From Anywhere Using the Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=222378) for controlling relays.

Comment: Just brainstorming: (1) If GSM/2G not available, we might consider LTE/4G SimModule (higher modules than SIM800/900), (2) Usually Rpi talks to SIM800 etc using python UART, so it is easy to python GPIO to trigger a 5V relay. PS - I also have a list of relays (including 16 channel) to suggest: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99988/how-to-wire-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-16-channel-relay-module-it-wont-work

Comment: Your recommendation "Quectel EC25 Mini PCle 4G/LTE Module + sixfab Raspberry Pi 3G-4G/LTE Base Shield V2 https://sixfab.com/product/quectel-ec25-mini-pcle-4glte-module/" is very good (though a bit expensive). I am particularly impressed by their well thought design for makers and newbies alike. For example, the "three header" flexibility alone makes them good value for money.

Comment: @tlfong01 Agreed. It's a bit expensive. I wanted to talk about prices but @ famedoro didn't mention anything about that, therefore, I skipped this part.

Comment: Ha, the OP is proposing a rather ambitious project, by hobbyist standards. If he is suggesting something for a small business, and in this case reliability is much more important than startup money. So for this type of sort of industrial app, I would strongly recommend SF products, though they might be three times more expensive than WS, as I said it is good value for your money, and if you take reliability into consideration, SF is cheap or cost effective. SF is expensive, because they use the PCIe bus which is also industrial standard. Similarly we should not compare Rpi3/4 with PCIe CM3/4.

Comment: Does the proposed GSM module allow me to recognize the calling number? I would like to use C as programming language, which database do you recommend me to use to store phone numbers and logs?

Comment: Certainly, you can recognize the caller ID/calling number. [Watch this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_l-AYxVOaw). It's about SIM900 which is a GSM/2G module. You can fire [AT Commands](https://www.pantechsolutions.net/blog/basic-at-commands-for-sim900a-gsmgprs-module/), though. || [This link](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/how-to-make-a-caller-identifier-with-leds-using-gsm-gprs) can be helpful for you.