# Relay is behaving differently from tutorial

Tags: gpio, python, relay

Given:
Raspberry Pi3
Sunfounder 2 channel relay
plugged into 3.3v
plugged into ground
plugged into pin 18

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
```

The light on the relay comes on only when I swap the high and low in the code that I saw on YouTube. Why is mine working backwards?

Mine has to be like the following snippet:

```
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Comment: Ah, there two types of relays: Yin and Yang. The following ENC SE Q&A clarifies well: "Relay : What is the difference between Low level trigger and high level trigger? Asked 2015nov25, Viewed 39k times":
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202680/relay-what-is-the-difference-between-low-level-trigger-and-high-level-trigger. Happy triggering. Cheers.

Comment: some relay modules have a jumper to switch between high and low trigger

Comment: And in case you think your relay is of the "wrong" type, and wants to get a "correct" one, here is a ***relay shopping guide***: "Rpi GPIO Controlling 5V Relay Problem Asked 2019jun26, Viewed 1k times":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99988/rpi-gpio-controlling-5v-relay-problem. And if you are of the "can't make up my mind" type, you can, as @Jaromanda X suggests, get a "Jumper select High/Low trigger relay". Happy locking down shopping. Cheers..

Comment: One more confusing thing: Beside the High/Low trigger select jumper, there is another JD-Vcc jumper: The following confusion guide might help to clarify or confuse newbies further: "***Relay Newbie Total Confusion Guide*** (High/Low trig jumper vs JD-Vcc High/Low Vcc jumper) - Rpi.org Forum":
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php? f=37&t=234552&p=1436656&hilit=relay+jumper+tlfong01#p1436656. Cheers.

Comment: And here is the big picture: https://penzu.com/public/ea1dd169. Cheers.